# Phonegap Build issue of IOS app

Tags: ios, cordova, build, phonegap-build

I am getting problem while building my app in phonegap.

It shows that IOS certificates are locked as below:

[image]

But when i am clicking on that link i found signing Keys saction.

In that section the IOS key is unlocked as below

[image]

Please solve my problem guys